# Why does my render look like this?

Tags: rendering, lighting

How do I fix this lighting?
[image: here]

please help me Im really confused :(

Comment: you have one light below and to the left of the object. add some more lights.

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you start out, you get one point light (called a "lamp") that shines equally in all directions. It looks like part of your character is above the light, so the light is shining up onto it. Try converting it into a Sun lamp—with a sun lamp, it doesn't matter where the lamp is, just which way it's pointing.